# Point app2 to use the default mongodb of app1 in app2 settings.json

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have 2 Meteor apps, app1 is running, and with the additional terminal `meteor mongo` showing:

> MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb

app2 is located in a sibbling folder of app1 folder. app2 has settings.json with this in it:

> {
> "env": {
> "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/"
> }
> }

app2 will be running on port 4000 and in app1 server file, I try to connect to app2 by ddp `app2Conn = DDP.connect('http://localhost:4000');`

I am getting undefined when app2 tries to connect to app1 collections. How can I let app2 use the same mongodb that app1 is using?
Thanks

**update after changine windows 10 env. variable**
Added a new enviroment variable to windows 10 where `variable = MONGO_URL` and the `value = mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/ meteor` as suggested in one of the answers below and open a new cmd to run `meteor run --port 4000` gave the error  `Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined` on `Meteor.users.findOne` code line for a document known to be present.

Answer (score 0):

MONGO_URL is an environment variable, not a setting (Meteor.settings). You need to set it before launching meteor in your `app2` project folder:

```sh
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/ meteor
```